# How to get text from gmail and paste that text in another tab using selenium web driver

Tags: facebook, selenium-webdriver

I have one test case like,when I forget password in any application like facebook or myAT&T site,i have to click forget password link and then I will enter email and click submit.After that a temporary password is send to the email.My task is that,to get that temporary password and switch to the old tab and paste that text in the temporary password text box.

Is there any solution for this,please help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance,

Santhosh

Comment: Do you want script to do process of forget password? OR direct want script which copy temporary password and paste at specific place?   Also from where can see temporary password? you need to copy it from mail?

Answer (score 0):

I'll never do it the way you want to do. Meaning, launching gmail and copying the password from the browser. It consumes more time and i'm not testing gmail. There are two possible solutions I can think of.

1. In regression environment, set the password generated to a constant value if possible. And use the same in the test. in this approach we are not testing "email send" mechanism of the app, if that is not the intent of the test use this approach. Most simple one.
2. Use a email client library, they are available in all the languages (eg: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8293945/1520443). Use it to assess the password mail that is sent to your gmail.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to open a new tab ? You can create a new instance of the browser,work on it(in your case get the password) and then destroy it.

Having multiple instances will give you more control rather than same instance with multiple tabs (unless you test case really means to do that).